# Accessing a structure through another structure member in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to access a structure using another structure. From the below program, element is the member of Node. At this line " **temp->element *e_temp;**", I couldn't link the "element" member of Node to the "elements" structure object.
compile error says "'e_temp' was not declared in this scope". What am I missing?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
typedef struct Elements
{
    int data;
    struct Elements *next;
}elements;

typedef struct Node
{
    int sno;
    elements *element;
    struct Node *next;
}node;

void add(int sno, vector<int> a)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = new node;

    temp->element *e_temp;
    e_temp = new elements;


    temp->sno = sno;
    while(a.size())
    {
        temp->e_temp->data = a[0];
        temp->e_temp = temp->e_temp->next;
        a.erase(a.begin());    
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> a{1,2,3};
    int sno = 1;
    add(sno, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `*e_temp` pointing? Where is it declared? How is it passed to `add`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to declare a local you can do `auto e_temp = new elements` but what i think you want is this for that line `temp->element = new elements;`
and then follow up with the rest of your code to reference temp's element instead of e_temp.

```
    temp->element->data = a[0];
    temp->element = temp->element->next
```

Also, i'd try to get out the habit of using `new` and use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was similar to the discussion with vclloarec

Answer (score 0):

The correct declaration for e_temp is

```
elements * e_temp;
```

but `e_temp` is not use of any part of your code.

Comment: When I change that, there is an error at  "temp->e_temp->data = a[0];" and " temp->e_temp = temp->e_temp->next;", saying that- error: 'node' has no member named 'e_temp'.

Comment: e_temp is not a member of node, it is a elements object wich is not a member of any object. The member of node is element. You are a bit confuse in your code. May be you could try temp->element=temp->element->next.  Your e_temp is not use.

Comment: Yeah, It worked now. I guess I was confused with the pointers. been so long since I had worked on this.